# is there anything like sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable in symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

There is really great widget in symfony 1. It provides standard input[type=file] with file url and delete checkbox.

Is there anything similar in symfony2?

I use symfony 2.3.